# Can I use the js/examples within a Typescript/Ionic Project?

Tags: typescript, three.js, ionic3

I am  trying to use it on ionic3 Framework(Typescript).

I import threejs by

```
import * as THREE from ‘three’;
```

But when I try to use

```
this.effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(this.renderer);
```

The debug says: `StereoEffect is not a constructor`

How can I use this examples on threejs typescript library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085132/using-three-js-in-angular2

Comment: Also checkout this https://github.com/amcdnl/ng2-three-demo

Comment: I already used threejs on typescript, my problem is when i have to use the threejs examples like orbitcontrols or StereoEffect,